# Fast grep on huge csv files

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file (`queryids.txt`) with a list of 847 keywords to search. I have to grep the keywords from about 12 huge csv files (the biggest has 2,184,820,000 lines). Eventually we will load it into a database of some sort but for now, we just want certain keywords to be grep'ed.

My command is:

```
LC_ALL=C fgrep -f queryids.txt subject.csv
```

I am thinking of writing a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.csv
do
    ( echo "Processing $f"
    filename=$(basename "$f")
    filename="${filename%.*}"
    LC_ALL=C fgrep -f queryids.txt $f > $filename"_goi.csv" ) &
done
```

and I will run it using: `nohup bash myscript.sh &`

The queryids.txt looks like this:

```
ENST00000401850
ENST00000249005
ENST00000381278
ENST00000483026
ENST00000465765
ENST00000269080
ENST00000586539
ENST00000588458
ENST00000586292
ENST00000591459
```

The subject file looks like this:

```
target_id,length,eff_length,est_counts,tpm,id
ENST00000619216.1,68,2.65769E1,0.5,0.300188,00065a62-5e18-4223-a884-12fca053a109
ENST00000473358.1,712,5.39477E2,8.26564,0.244474,00065a62-5e18-4223-a884-12fca053a109
ENST00000469289.1,535,3.62675E2,4.82917,0.212463,00065a62-5e18-4223-a884-12fca053a109
ENST00000607096.1,138,1.92013E1,0,0,00065a62-5e18-4223-a884-12fca053a109
ENST00000417324.1,1187,1.01447E3,0,0,00065a62-5e18-4223-a884-12fca053a109
```

I am concerned this will take a long time. Is there a faster way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Most of the time is taken reading the CSV files. That has to be done regardless of how you structure the loop, and you can't make it go any faster. `queryids.txt` is tiny, so re-reading it for each file is not going to make any significant difference.

Comment: Just to complete the question - please [edit] it to include the expected output given the 2 input files you posted.

Comment: You have a CSV file with two _billion_ lines? _"Eventually we will load it into a database of some sort but for now"_ Let me guess, you've been saying this every year for ten years? :) Quit feeding your technical debt!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not really. Just to make it clear, I just got access to these files and was told to make a csv to eventually upload to a database but they wanted some data by end of this week. That's the simplest way I could do it because I have no knowledge regarding databases.

Comment: Doesn't take more than a few minutes to find `LOAD DATA INFILE` and a quick tutorial on setting up a MySQL database. Then you're practically done, you've done it the right way, the process doesn't take five weeks to execute, and you've learnt something useful at the same time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things I can suggest to improve the performance:

1. No need to spawn a sub-shell using `( .. ) &`, you can use braces `{ ... } &` if needed.
2. Use `grep -F` (non-regex or fixed string search) to make `grep` run faster
3. Avoid `basename` command and use `bash` string manipulation

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.csv; do
    echo "Processing $f"
    filename="${f##*/}"
    LC_ALL=C grep -Ff queryids.txt "$f" > "${filename%.*}_goi.csv"
done
```

I suggest you run this on a smaller dataset to compare the performance gain.

Comment: `fgrep` is analogous to `grep -F` with the previous being deprecated in favor of the latter..

Comment: Yes I overlooked use of `fgrep` in OP's script.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I have also added details on the files to give it more context.

Comment: The `&` starts a new process anyway; I'm not sure, but I think `bash` is able to recognize that the `(...)` is run in the background and only forks once. The overhead of `basename` is negligible compare to the runtime of `grep`.

Comment: @KomalRathi, you being a Bioinformatics student and this one .csv having over 2 billion lines seems kinda exciting to me. Is it by any chance possible that this csv is public?

Comment: Does it really help starting the greps parallel sharing the I/O or can you remove the `&` from loop and grep them one file after another?

Comment: Yes I agree with you, putting individual `grep` commands in background won't really help considering huge size of files.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this instead:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    while ( (getline line < "queryids.txt") > 0  ) {
        re = ( re=="" ? "" : re "|") line
    }
}
FNR==1 { close(out); out=FILENAME; sub(/\.[^.]+$/,"_goi&",out) }
$0 ~ re { print > out }
' *.csv
```

It's using a regexp rather than string comparison - whether or not that matters and, if so, what we can do about it depends on the values in queryids.txt. In fact there may be a **vastly** faster and more robust way to do this depending on what your files contain so if you edit your question to include some examples of your file contents we could be of more help.

I see you have now posted some sample input and indeed we can do this much faster and more robustly by using a hash lookup:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    FS="."
    while ( (getline line < "queryids.txt") > 0  ) {
        ids[line]
    }
}
FNR==1 { close(out); out=FILENAME; sub(/\.[^.]+$/,"_goi&",out) }
$1 in ids { print > out }
' *.csv
```

Comment: I have added details on the files to give it more context.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show the much faster approach at the end.

Comment: I'd be surprised if `grep -f` didn't already do this internally if it is, in fact, faster. `grep` is pretty well optimized. I'd be *very* surprised if scanning the file line-by-line in `awk` is faster than `grep`'s own search.

Comment: I wouldn't since grep is searching the whole of each line for each id appearing anywhere on that line instead of just doing a hash lookup of a key field from each line. grep is searching for any of the ids anywhere on each line vs awk doing a hash lookup of THE key field from the line. That's a huge difference in complexity. Plus the loop+greps has to load the ids file once for every other CSV. I expect the awk with hashing will be an order of magnitude faster than the shell loop with greps.

Comment: @chepner plus the awk/hash solution is more robust than the loop/grep since it's only looking at the the key field on each line for an exact match so it can't find any false or partial matches anywhere else on each line.

Comment: `awk` still has to scan the entire line to do the field splitting; you don't get `$1` for free.

Comment: I know but awk is highly optimized to do that. Hopefully the OP will do some timed testing of both approaches and post their results.